# Page not updating after ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a custom component (that is, an xhtml file with ui:composition inside) where I have a file upload field. When a file is selected it is uploaded via AJAX like this

```xml
<uc:fileUpload
  id="#{id}fileUploadComponent"
  idSuffix="#{id}fileUploadSuffix"
  value="#{fileUpload.docsFilePart}"
  accept="#{fieldWrapper.acceptedFileTypes}"
  widgetVar="#{id}documentUploadWidget"
  nullAllowed="#{!((fieldDef.mandatory and 
  fieldWrapper.getCurrentFileCount() lt 1) and isSaving)}"
  maxSize="#{customField.maxFileSize}" >                                     
  <f:ajax listener="#{fileUpload.uploadNewFile(fieldWrapper)}" render="#{localId}fileUploadMain messages"/>
</uc:fileUpload>
```

Below this upload there's a `<div>` with the same id as specified in the `render` attribute of the ajax call, where links for downloading the files are shown. What happens is weird - after a file is selected, it is uploaded, the `<div>` is updated correctly with a link to the newly uploaded file. However when I click "Cancel" or "Save" on the page, their according actions are called, a correct response is returned to the browser (with status 200) but the browser seems to ignore it - the page is not visually updated or anything...

The custom component is quite big piece of code with not-so-easy-to-rewrite logic so replacing it at this point will be... hard...

One thing to not might be that uploading the file happens in a separate controller, while the main page controller is another one. This is because the separate controller is supposed to handle uploads from the custom component.

I can't really understand what exactly happens, even less why, and I'll appreciate any ideas!

For what it's worth, I am using Mojarra on Wildfly 11 (the one provided by the AS)

Comment: I will try to do an MCVE, but, honestly, this is something very weird and I was hoping   someone could just share some magic insight. On the other hand, doing an MCVE will probably help me understand exactly what causes the problem, thus helping me fix it, so thanks @kukeltje , will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the reason is that file uploading via JSF AJAX causes the creation of an iframe called "JSFFrameId" and that frame being set as the target of the nesting form. After the AJAX request completes the target is not removed/cleared thus causing responses to go into that iframe and breaking the view.
At this point I am not sure what causes this, but a workaround for me is to have `onevent` in the `<f:ajax>` definition, that clears the form target, like this:

```xml
<f:ajax 
  listener="#{fileUpload.uploadNewFile(fieldWrapper)}"
  onevent="function(e){if (e.status == 'complete') { $(e.source).parents('form').attr('target','');}"
  render="#{localId}fileUploadMain messages">
```

I will check what other states may need handling but basically this solves the problem. It may be useful if someone shares their suspicions on what may have caused JSF to leave behind this iframe and not reset the target of the form.